# Can I use Core Data fetched properties to return the most recent entity?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data

I have two Entities that have a relationship like so...

[image: Core Data]

I want to create a fetched property on the conversation to return the most recent message that belongs to it. I don't want to have to maintain another relationship so having a fetched property seems like the way to go.

So what this boils down to is;

**How can I limit the fetched property to one item?**

and

**How can I sort the items by timestamp?**

Comment: This is very basic, you will need to add an `NSSortDescriptor` to you `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I thought a fetched property was used instead of the `NSFetchRequest`. (e.g `NSArray *array = conversation.fetchedProperty;`)

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question. I don't know if or how to use fetchedProperties.

Comment: No problem. If you know anyone who might, I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a fetched property to solve that problem but there is a catch.

You **can't** define that fetched property in the model editor.

You **can** define that fetched property in code.

So yes, you can do it but the value is very low.

### Update

> Have you got an example of defining a fetched property in code? Where would I do this? The managedObjectModel?

Yes you would do this through the `NSManagedObjectModel`.

1. You must do the edit before the model is added to a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  As soon as a `NSManagedObjectModel` is added to a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` it becomes immutable.
2. You grab the entity you care about and then then create a `NSFetchedPropertyDescription`.
3. Add that `NSFetchedPropertyDescription` to the existing entity.
4. Add the `NSFetchRequest` to the created `NSFetchedPropertyDescription`.

Once that is done you can then use the `NSManagedObjectModel` like normal.  Pretty straight forward other than having to reach into the model which is unusual.  The order that you do things is important.  Take this example:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
ZAssert(mom, @"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

//Inject a fetched property
NSEntityDescription *parentEntity = [mom entitiesByName][@"Parent"];

NSFetchedPropertyDescription *fetchedProperty = [[NSFetchedPropertyDescription alloc] init];
[fetchedProperty setName:@"lastTestEntity"];

NSMutableArray *properties = [[parentEntity properties] mutableCopy];
[properties addObject:fetchedProperty];
[parentEntity setProperties:properties];

NSFetchRequest *testEntityRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[testEntityRequest setEntity:[mom entitiesByName][@"TestEntity"]];
[testEntityRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == $FETCH_SOURCE"]];
[testEntityRequest setFetchLimit:1];

NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:NO];
[testEntityRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortByDate]];

[fetchedProperty setFetchRequest:testEntityRequest];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
ZAssert(coordinator, @"Failed to initialize coordinator");
```

Notice how I set the `NSFetchRequest` after the `NSFetchedProperty` has been added to the `NSEntityDescription`.  If you do not set it afterwards you will get an error from Core Data.  Radar has been filed but I suspect very few people have even looked at this stuff let alone filed a radar against the odd behavior.

Comment: Have you got an example of defining a fetched property in code? Where would I do this? The `managedObjectModel`?

Comment: How did you find out about this? I have not found any documentation. Btw in model editor, I can add a fetched property to an entity, however the only thing we can set there is "Predicate" which takes a string - so we can't do sorting there right? And also, generating the entity to code (Editor>Create NSM... subclass...) does not make a visible property for accessing the fetched property. So I don't know how to fetch that even, but will try to understand by looking at your sample code from now.

Comment: I learned through experimentation.  The model editor is very limited and not very useful.  As for making the property visible, it is as visible this way as it would be with the model editor.  It would still be defined as a `@dynamic` property on the `NSManagedObject`.  Nothing would change.

Answer (score 0):

```
// - MARK: - swift version

let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "momd")
        var mom: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil
        if let modelURL = modelURL {
            mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        }
        ZAssert(mom, "%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", type(of: self), NSStringFromSelector(#function))
    
        //Inject a fetched property
        //
    
    
        let parentEntity = mom.entitiesByName["Parent"]
    
        let fetchedProperty = NSFetchedPropertyDescription()
        fetchedProperty.name = "lastTestEntity"
    
        var properties = parentEntity.properties()
        properties.append(fetchedProperty)
        parentEntity.properties = properties
    
        let testEntityRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        testEntityRequest.entity = mom.entitiesByName["TestEntity"]
        testEntityRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == $FETCH_SOURCE")
        testEntityRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    
        let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createDate", ascending: false)
        testEntityRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByDate]
    
        fetchedProperty.fetchRequest = testEntityRequest
    
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        ZAssert(coordinator, "Failed to initialize coordinator")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).